# How does new Map() works in javascript when the json has keys with same name

Tags: javascript, json, hashmap

I have a JSON structure and code like below :

```
const villages = 
{
"lossesOccured":
    [
        {
            "type": "destroyed",
            "affectedOn": "humans",
            "quantity": 120,
            "reliefFund": 100000,
            "location": {
                "district": "thanjavur",
                "villageName": "madukkur",
                "pincode": "614903"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "physicalDamage",
            "affectedOn": "humans",
            "quantity": 250,
            "reliefFund": 50000,
            "location": {
                "district": "thanjavur",
                "villageName": "madukkur",
                "pincode": "614903"
            }
        },
    ]
}

const lossesArray = villages.lossesOccured

let myMap = new Map()

lossesArray.forEach(loss => {
    if(loss.affectedOn === "humans"){
        myMap.set(loss.affectedOn,loss)
    }
})

 console.log(myMap)
```

Initialised a new Map and assigned key,values to it.
Key is "affectedOn". 
Since there are same key names(affectedOn) in many elements, map eliminates all duplicates and prints only one. Is there a way to print all the key values even-though it has same name.
Thanks in advance.

Output:
[image: Map]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Map has key-value pairs, similar to an object, and will have a value for every *distinct* key. (If you want to use keys `k1` and `k2`, and `k1 === k2`, and you call `myMap.set(k1` and then later `myMap.set(k2`, then the initial value assigned by `k1` will be overwritten.)

If you want to turn *everything* in your input array into a `Map`, one way to make sure the keys are unique would be to make the keys *objects* (which won't be `===` to each other):

```
myMap.set({ key: loss.affectedOn }, loss);
```

```js
const villages = {
  "lossesOccured": [{
      "type": "destroyed",
      "affectedOn": "humans",
      "quantity": 120,
      "reliefFund": 100000,
      "location": {
        "district": "thanjavur",
        "villageName": "madukkur",
        "pincode": "614903"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "physicalDamage",
      "affectedOn": "humans",
      "quantity": 250,
      "reliefFund": 50000,
      "location": {
        "district": "thanjavur",
        "villageName": "madukkur",
        "pincode": "614903"
      }
    },
  ]
}

const lossesArray = villages.lossesOccured

const myMap = new Map();
lossesArray.forEach(loss => {
  if (loss.affectedOn === "humans") {
    myMap.set({ key: loss.affectedOn }, loss);
  }
});

console.log(myMap);
```